# natural way to reverse tooth decay fast

Tags: food, personal-care, comfort

Most people would run to a dentist to solve their tooth decay problem if their tooth is severely decaying, however I'm looking for a natural way that works to help restore teeth.

Some people have suggested oil pulling and some suggested fermented cod liver oil with high-vitamin butter. One even reported xylitol to reverse cavities.

Currently I'm trying everything and I want to know if there are other things I can do to naturally reverse cavities faster myself without seeing a dentist.

I believe if plants can regrow from seed, teeth can. Does anyone have ideas what else I can use and/or not use to help reverse cavities?

Comment: [Miswak toothbrushes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3545237/) have been around for ages. I'm not sure if this will work on its own. Other than that, a boiled ginger mouthwash leaves your mouth feeling very refreshed. A boiled sage mouthwash may also be good.

Answer (score 10):

No. You should go see a Dentist, who are experts in Dental Hygiene, and are the only persons opinions who you should trust.

Comment: Seriously, don't ask random people on a site about Lifehacks for tips on Dental Hygiene. You'll just make your teeth worse.

Comment: After reading thousands of pages on the internet, I learn that going to a typical dentist can make things worse because drilling holes can eventually wreck teeth and root canals means losing a live tooth for an artificial one and that it can trap bacteria. A crown blocks access to the tooth inside meaning it can be more difficult to feed real nutrients to them. I had to post here because I'd rather have a natural solution for a few dozen dollars than have a dentist artificialize my mouth to their standards for thousands of dollars.

Answer (score 6):

Cavities **cannot be reversed**. Teeth aren't growing tissue, they don't repair, grow back, heal etc: they simply aren't made of the right kind of material for that.

Teeth don't grow back. They just don't.

Answer (score 3):

Your only natural option of restoring tooth health is [becoming a shark](http://animals.mom.me/can-sharks-regrow-teeth-11118.html).

All you can do otherwise is cut down on the consumption of whatever is harming your teeth, improve your dental hygiene, and visit a dentist.

Answer (score -4):

Your belief that teeth can 'regrow' isn't exactly right, but that said, the old and firmly established idea that cavities cannot heal themselves or be reversed has been proved to be erroneous, with the caveat that, if the decay is severe and the tooth is painful, particularly if the root is affected, its a trip to the dentist before you get an abcess. In those circumstances, its unfortunately already too late for your tooth to heal itself.

However, research in the last few years does indicate that small cavities in teeth do heal themselves, given the right conditions, and in the UK and parts of Europe for the last decade or so, small cavities are left by the dentist to see if they heal themselves with improved dental hygiene. I know that they can do, having had personal experience of this with a younger relative.

A change in diet might be necessary depending on what you currently consume, and there's some interesting information in the link below, garnered from various scientific sources, including The Lancet (a well respected British medical publication). Having read it myself, I'm off to do further research, given I eat whole oats daily, and am also currently looking at the role of proteolytic enzymes regarding tooth decay and other health issues, another area of interest. I've not provided a link to the enzyme situation because I'm still researching it.

http://draxe.com/naturally-reverse-cavities-heal-tooth-decay/

Whilst this answer does answer your question, any solutions are not 'fast' - and whether any of this actually counts as a Hack, I can't quite decide.

UPDATE:

I have found the British Medical Journal report, also published in the Dental Association's Journal in the UK, and the link is below - however, if you want to access it properly, you have to pay, and I ain't that desperate to prove this information accurate!

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2520490/

Comment: I don't really think I put any faith in a link from the site "Dr. Axe". For starters, he's a DC not an MD. Second, a quick google suggests [the guy has no idea what he's talking about](http://www.overcomeobesity.org/overcome-obesity/research/josh-axe-d-c-spewing-a-bunch-of-nonsense-on-the-dr-oz-show/). This is exactly why Lifehacks shouldn't have health questions inside it's scope.

Comment: Oh, he's also an [anti-vaxxer](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/friendlyatheist/2015/01/28/why-did-about-com-invite-an-anti-vaxxer-to-be-one-of-its-health-experts-2/).

Comment: That maybe so - but I have personal experience in the UK of cavities being left and of them healing themselves, so whether you trust Dr. Axe or not is largely irrelevant - he is citing scientific sources. But I will look for a more 'serious' link....

Comment: You can't really claim his sources are accurate without investigating them yourself.

Comment: See updated answer....

Comment: That article is over 80 years old. Do you have a more recent study?

Comment: Can't find anything else, might be in a professional dentist publication that I can't access, but I'm seeing my dentist next week, and will ask her for the reference - she's the one who confirmed my son's cavity wouldn't be treated because of latest research two years ago, so when I do, I'll post it here.

Comment: Wipqozn, there are stories that before grains and sugars were the norm, people never experienced decay. Back in the day, toothbrushes and toothpaste did not even exist.

Comment: Look at papers published by John Featherstone, MSc, PhD who is high up at the UCSF dental school. Or take his terrific "Caries Management by Risk Assessment" class the next time it is offered on Coursera (meant for practicing dentists, but they don't check id at the keyboard). Roughly it said: badly decayed teeth can't be undone BUT tiny flaws can be undone by tipping the balance in the direction of the remineralizing the tooth. (less snacking, no dry mouth, more flouride, appropriate cleaning multiple times/day) GREAT course. https://www.coursera.org/course/cariesmanagement has references.

Comment: Aye, thats what I'm saying, and is the info I've been given